# JSS resize images on table HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, web-applications

i'm doing a webapplication for android and iOS
i'm resizing every object in my html file by Javascript
but there's a problem, the first table it's perfect 
but when i copy it down the image of the second table doesn't resize, can you help me please?

this is the site

http://bestparty.altervista.org/IOS/IOS/eventi.php

this is .JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").css("height", ((($(window).height() * 100) / 100)));
  $("#evntfoto").css("height", ((($(window).height() * 20) / 100)));
  $("#evntfoto").css("width", ((($(window).width() * 40) / 100)));



  document.ontouchstart = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
});
```

and this is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly">
    <meta content="on" http-equiv="cleartype">
    <link href="css/stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta content="width=320, initial-scale=0.7, user-scalable=no" name=
    "viewport">
    <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.1.js.js"></script><!--PER EVENTI-->

    <script src="JS/func.js"></script><!--PER EVENTI-->

    <title>BParty</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr valign="middle">
                <td align="center" valign="middle" width="25%">&lt;</td>

                <td align="center" valign="middle" width="50%">BPARTY</td>

                <td align="center" width="25%">&gt;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="evntprg">
        EVENTI IN PROGRAMMA
    </div>

    <div id="container" style="overflow:scroll;">
        <div style=
        "width:90%; display:block; margin:0 auto; padding-top:10px; margin-top:10px; padding-left:10px; background-color:#FFF; padding-bottom:10px;">
        <table width="100%">
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td align="center" id="evntfoto" style=
                    "background-image:url(IMG/fnky.jpg); background-position:center; background-size: cover;"
                    valign="middle"></td>

                    <td align="left" id="evnttxt" valign="top">&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <b>Fnky carnival</b><br>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; Sabato 21 Febbraio<br>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; Nikita<br></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table width="100%">
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td align="center" id="evntfoto" style=
                    "background-image:url(IMG/fnky.jpg); background-position:center; background-size: cover;"
                    valign="middle"></td>

                    <td align="left" id="evnttxt" valign="top">&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <b>Fnky carnival</b><br>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; Sabato 21 Febbraio<br>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; Nikita<br></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are using ID's. ID's in HTML are unique there only can be one.**

---

Change `id="eventfoto"` to `class="eventfoto"` in your HTML. Then in jQuery change your selectors to be `$(".evntfoto").` Some knowledge about **[HTML ID'S](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)**. The reason why you would use classes is because you can use more than one on the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Change below td width as 80%.

Static Html code :

```
<td valign="middle" align="center" id="evntfoto" style="height: 119px; width: 80%; background-image: url(http://bestparty.altervista.org/IOS/IOS/IMG/fnky.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%;">
                                        </td>
```

Dynamic code using jquery :

```
$("#evntfoto").css("width","80%");
```